# scrapy can't find spider after os.path.append

Tags: python, scrapy

My spider directories like below:

```
prjects
   |------spidername
   |           |---------spidername
   |                          |-----------spiders
   |                          |               |-----------spider1.py
   |                          |               |-----------spider2.py
   |                          |------------setting.py
   |                          |------------__init__.py
   |                          |------------myspiderentry.py
public
   |-------mylogger.py
   |-------utilities.py
```

I want start my spider by `python myspiderentry.py`, and in `myspiderentry.py`I invoke my spider like below:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

os.system("scrapy crawl spidername -a links=mylink")
```

It worked fine!
But when I try to import mylogger.py and do some custom log like below:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent,'public'))
import utilities 
import mylogger 

mylogger.log("begin")
os.system("scrapy crawl spidername -a links=mylink")
```

system report error like below:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spidername'
```

why?

Comment: Did you run file from the same working directory/locations? There may be some path changing happening inside your logging module.

Comment: I would add breakpoint() inside a file and see what is inside sys.path and make sure the file is running from correct folder. Also adding absolute folder path like /home/someone/folder_name may be a better option, if possible.

Comment: Why do you run the spider like that? [Read this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

Comment: Your first example would work even if you left out the import statements, please include the full traceback